# how to map List of string values to multiple variables with empty list values in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

`i need a solution as to how we can assign values to variables from a list of string

i have a list of string with six string values in it

```
var array = new List<string>(){"101", "10", "2", "50", "36", "8"};
```

and i need to assign these values to six different variables also i need to handle if all the six values are not present in list suppose only 2 values are present it should not throw exception.

e.g var 1, var2 ..... var 6

what i tried is following but getting exception as

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
> the collection.

```
if (mod != null && mod.Count > 0)
        {
            var 1 = mod[0] != null ? mod[0] : "";
            var 2 = mod[1] != null ? mod[1] : "";
            var 3 = mod[2] != null ? mod[2] : "";
            var 4 = mod[3] != null ? mod[3] : "";
            var 5 = mod[4] != null ? mod[4] : "";
            var 6 = mod[5] != null ? mod[5] : "";
        }
```

but with this approach one issue is that if count is less than 5 so suppose 2 then i am getting exception on mapping of var 3,4,5,6
i want to default empty string if values are not passed to list of length 6

need some solution for that

Comment: Why tho? Why the var? 
Should not try to fix before you get a more clear picture of what you wanna do. 
You have an array of string getting the strings out one by one into vars doesn't seems that usefull.

Comment: actually the variables are constants and need to be mapped to xml to send to third party api these variables are part of a class instead of original name i named it as var 1.2....6

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable.ElementAtOrdefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=net-7.0):

```
string s1 = array.ElementAtOrdefault(0) ?? "";
string s2 = array.ElementAtOrdefault(1) ?? "";
string s3 = array.ElementAtOrdefault(2) ?? "";
string s4 = array.ElementAtOrdefault(3) ?? "";
string s5 = array.ElementAtOrdefault(4) ?? "";
string s6 = array.ElementAtOrdefault(5) ?? "";
```

`ElementAtOrdefault` is using the indexer if possible, so it's not enumerating the list/array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting IndexOutOfRangeException is the following:

If your array is missing one (or more) value (from the six strings in your example), then its length will be shorter than 5, thus the line `var 6 = mod[5] != null ? mod[5] : "";` will throw you an exception, because `mod[5]` makes no sense when your array's length is smaller than 5.

To further assist you, please provide some information about your goals, as I would not necessarily create individual variables when they are already existing as members of an array.

Comment: actually the variables are constants and need to be mapped to xml to send to third party api these variables are part of a class instead of original name i named it as var 1.2....6 –